# Find number X by asking Hamming distance between X and Y in binary representation

Tags: xor

We need to find unknown 16-bit integer X. We can ask "how many '1'-bits in number X xor Y" (Y is 16-bit too). What best strategy to find X? Or what minimum number of questions?

For example, if answer for Y=0 is 1, we can do binarysearch-like strategy restoring X in 4 additional operations.

I have found set of 10 numbers {26330, 15436, 4730, 5006, 10083, 227, 2775, 2367, 17754, 25121} such if we ask about all of these, we can uniquely restore X.

Comment: 1. Are we allowed to choose queries adaptively?  In other words, are we allowed to pick the next query $Y$ based on the set of all answers to all prior queries? Or do we have to specify the list of all queries $Y$ in advance, before seeing the answers to any of them?  2. Relevant (but not identical): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game).  See especially Knuth's algorithm.

Comment: Yes, we can (as in example with one bit). But set of static questions is interesting too.

Comment: I think this can be solved in $\Theta(n/\log n)$ queries. [This paper seems relevant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0773)

Answer (score 1):

One reasonable heuristic would be to use a greedy algorithm, which at each step picks a query that is likely to reduce the space of possibilities as much as possible.

Suppose you care about the maximum number of questions (worst-case).  Then I suggest the following strategy.  At any point, you have a set $S$ of possible values of $X$ that remain.  For each possible query $Y$ and each possible response $R$ to that query, let $n(Y,R)$ denote how many possibilities of $S$ would remain consistent with the response $R$ to query $Y$.  Define $n(Y) = \max_R n(Y,R)$.  Now, choose the query $Y$ that makes $n(Y)$ as small as possible.  [This is basically [Knuth's minimax algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game)#Five-guess_algorithm).]

Alternatively, suppose you care about the expected number of questions asked (average-case).  Then do the same, except now define $h(Y)$ to be the entropy of a random variable that takes on the value $R$ with probability $n(Y,R) / |S|$.  In other words, define

$$h(Y) = - \sum_R {n(Y,R) \over |S|} \lg {n(Y,R) \over |S|}.$$

Then choose the query $Y$ that minimizes $h(Y)$.

There is no guarantee that these procedures are optimal, but I bet they're pretty good.

Related but not the same: you might also be interested in [Ulam's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam%27s_game), a generalization of the game of 20 questions.  Also, take a look at [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130125014055/http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-tol/2010-March/000912.html), which describes an algorithm for 20 questions based on entropy calculations.